# providing smooth shading material

Tags: ami.js

I am using ami.js for a brain research project. The objective is to load a brain model that is colored smooth shaded but here are the issues:

a) The original stl model that I have, does not have the normals and it seems to be impossible to compute them at least with the three version ami use.
[original stl model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfMYw.jpg)

b) I have the same model with computed normals but in ply format that Unfortunately is not supported yet. (PLYLoader)
[ply with normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjcO4.jpg)

Is there a way to load and smooth the stl model or I can use the PLYLoader in a clean way.

pdta: I easily load the model using a clean three js(r93)+[PLYLoader](https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/PLYLoader.js)

Comment: The models generation/visualization should be independent from ami. Also it should work fine with the latest three. Did you try to use three r93 + ply loader + ami? If you just want to load the brain model you may not even need ami

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I already included threer93 succesfully, if you want it is possible to update the readme of ami.js and I can provide the example with a ply file.
BR, Esteban